# iOS - JAVA - JSON - Invalid JSON escape sequence for unicode

Tags: java, ios, json, unicode, unicode-escapes

We are sending Unicode strings in JSON. but IOS automatically converts character into their Unicodes, due to which it is converting in codes like : \U0928

Now the issue is from JAVA side its being converted into Object where it crashes because of Capital U in to Unicodes and Giving Error " Invalid JSON Escape sequence ".

We tried to use stringByReplacingOccurenceOfString Method to replace \U with \u, but event though it is not sending \u.

Comment: Why don't you on the Java side convert the string's \U with \u?